# can't cast QMainWindow from QMdiSubWindow

Tags: qt, casting, mdi

So i have a program that uses a subclass of QMainWindow for QMdiArea widgets. I'm only doing this because QDockWidgets can only be used in a QMainWindow (and my subclass needed dock widgets).

I was testing my class's serialization for saving purposes and my pointer wasn't correct. Here is the code

```
    if (ui->mdiMain->subWindowList().length() > 0)
    {
        QString path = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, "Save Build Order", "" ,"*.cbo");

        if (path > 0)
        {
            QFile file(path, this);
            if (file.open(QFile::WriteOnly) == true)
            {
                QWidget* widget = reinterpret_cast<QWidget*>(ui->mdiMain->activeSubWindow());
                WidgetBuildOrder* widgetBuildOrder = reinterpret_cast<WidgetBuildOrder*>(widget);

                QDataStream stream(&file);
                stream << widgetBuildOrder;

                file.close();
                ui->statusBar->showMessage("Save Successful.", 5000);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

WidgetBuildOrder is a subclass of MainWindow.

so my thought was that I could keep casting the pointer to what it actually is. When I created the MDI area, i passed a new WidgetBuildOrder. Is there a way to do this?

To Clarify, after the casting I do get a pointer its just pointing to garbage. Not the values set in the WidgetBuildOrder I actually have open.

Any help will be appreciated,

Thanks,

Jec

Comment: Did you redefine the `operator <<` for your class `WidgetBuildOrder` or are you trying to serialize a widget ?

Comment: i redefined it. The issue is the pointer to the WidgetBuildOrder is not pointing to the same object that i passed to the QMdiWindow (mdiMain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QMdiArea::activeSubWindow` returns a `QMdiSubWindow*`, or 0 it the `QMdiArea` doesn't have the focus.

As you can't possibly have a class that inherits from `QMainWindow` and `QMdiSubWindow`, what you want is to get the widget inside the **current** sub-window:

```
QMdiSubWindow *subWindow = ui->mdiMain->currentSubWindow();
WidgetBuildOrder* widgetBuildOrder = 
    static_cast<WidgetBuildOrder*>(subwindow->widget());
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to not give the WidgetBuildOrder pointer the pointer of the QWidget but the activatedSubWindow to get the right object back?

Something like:

```
//QWidget* widget = reinterpret_cast<QWidget*>(ui->mdiMain->activeSubWindow());
WidgetBuildOrder* widgetBuildOrder = reinterpret_cast<WidgetBuildOrder*>(ui->mdiMain->activeSubWindow());
```

Comment: Unfortunately I got the same results. Several of widgetBuildOrder's objects were either null pointers or contained garbage values. Thanks for the help